# How do I fix wire-format data error when applying in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I have this following yaml file:

#deployment.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
      - containerPort: 80
```

That I'm trying to apply with this command:

`kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`

I have checked if could be something with indentation, replaced tabs for spaces but I keep getting this error

`error: proto: cannot parse invalid wire-format data`

I also have the same error when applying from template

`kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/application/deployment.yaml`

Comment: can also add response of `kubectl version`

Answer (score 1):

In your snippet, there some indentation issues in `.spec.template.spec.containers` section. Your indentations should be like this:

```
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx:1.14.2
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```